# Oval Shape in Overlay View in .Net MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I'm upgrading my Xamarin Forms project to .Net MAUI and I need to place a rectangle on top of a CameraPreview with a transparent circle in the center, as shown in the following image:

[Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SQJt.png)

To do this, I followed the same example that is present on this [Blog](https://www.xamboy.com/2019/02/23/overlayview-in-xamarin-forms/) But I'm having trouble doing it in .Net MAUI.

I'm having problems adapting this part of the code in .Net MAUI:

```html
public class NativeOverlayView : View
{
        Bitmap windowFrame;
        float overlayOpacity = 0.5f;
        bool showOverlay = false;
        
        public bool ShowOverlay
        {
            get { return showOverlay; }
            set
            {
                bool repaint = !showOverlay;
                showOverlay = value;
                if (repaint)
                {
                    Redraw();
                }
            }
        }


        public float Opacity
        {
            get { return overlayOpacity; }
            set
            {
                overlayOpacity = value;
                Redraw();
            }
        }

        Color overlayColor = Color.Gray;
        public Color OverlayBackgroundColor
        {
            get { return overlayColor; }
            set
            {
                overlayColor = value;
                Redraw();

            }
        }

        OverlayShape overlayShape = OverlayShape.Circle;

        public OverlayShape Shape
        {
            get { return overlayShape; }
            set
            {
                overlayShape = value;
                Redraw();

            }
        }


        public NativeOverlayView(Context context, bool showOverlay = false) : base(context)
        {
            ShowOverlay = showOverlay;
            SetWillNotDraw(false);
        }

        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.OnDraw(canvas);
            if (ShowOverlay)
            {
                if (windowFrame == null)
                {
                    CreateWindowFrame();
                }
                canvas.DrawBitmap(windowFrame, 0, 0, null);
            }
        }
        void Redraw()
        {
            if (ShowOverlay)
            {
                windowFrame?.Recycle();
                windowFrame = null;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
        void CreateWindowFrame()
        {
            float width = this.Width;
            float height = this.Height;
          
            windowFrame = Bitmap.CreateBitmap((int)width, (int)height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
            Canvas osCanvas = new Canvas(windowFrame);
            Paint paint = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias)
            {
                Color = OverlayBackgroundColor,
                Alpha = (int)(255 * Opacity)
            };

            RectF outerRectangle = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);

            osCanvas.DrawRect(outerRectangle, paint);

            paint.SetXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.Clear));


            switch(Shape)
            {
                case OverlayShape.Circle:

                    float radius = Math.Min(width,height) * 0.45f;
                    osCanvas.DrawCircle(width / 2, (height / 2), radius, paint);

                    break;
                default:

                    Path path = new Path();
                    // Starting point
                    path.MoveTo(width / 2, height / 5);

                    // Upper left path
                    path.CubicTo(5 * width / 14, 0,
                            0, height / 15,
                            width / 28, 2 * height / 5);

                    // Lower left path
                    path.CubicTo(width / 14, 2 * height / 3,
                            3 * width / 7, 5 * height / 6,
                            width / 2, height);

                    // Lower right path
                    path.CubicTo(4 * width / 7, 5 * height / 6,
                            13 * width / 14, 2 * height / 3,
                            27 * width / 28, 2 * height / 5);

                    // Upper right path
                    path.CubicTo(width, height / 15,
                            9 * width / 14, 0,
                            width / 2, height / 5);

                    osCanvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
                    break;
            }


        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
            windowFrame?.Recycle();
            windowFrame = null;
        }
}
```

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you add some of your code may be i can help you

Answer (score 0):

> I'm upgrading my Xamarin Forms project to .Net MAUI

About upgrading a Xamarin.Forms app to a .NET MAUI app, you can check out the  documentations: [Migrate a Xamarin.Forms custom renderer to a .NET MAUI handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/renderer-to-handler) | [Reuse custom renderers in .NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/custom-renderers).

For more details and steps you can refer to the official wiki: [Porting Custom Renderers to Handlers](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Porting-Custom-Renderers-to-Handlers).